# md-icon .svg not visible on chrome

Tags: html, angular-material

I am using angular material where I used 'md-icon' as

`<md-icon md-svg-src="icons/menu.svg" class="menu"></md-icon>`

It works fine in firefox, but icons are not visible on chrome. Does anyone have the idea about this?

Comment: Any chance you can include a code sample that breaks? I don't see any open issues related to this, and it's kinda hard to debug without a failing example :-)

Comment: I am unable to give sample code because I am using downloaded icons.. the icons from the internet are visible on chrome but not downloaded icons.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I'm having the same issue and icons are not showing in Chrome but only on Mac.

Comment: @Dimple I spent some time debugging and I found out it was because of the shadow filter I applied on the icons that was making them invisible. Possibly a bug in WebKit.